# NTLM Authentication with GetHttpConnection

Tags: visual-c++, ntlm

I have a VC++ (6.0) app.  We want to use NTLM Authentication to access a server.  I prompt for the URL, ID, and Password and send these in my internetSession.GetHttpConnection call, and if you enter the domain\id and the password, it works fine, using NTLM.

We want users who are currently logged in on the same domain as the server to not have to enter their ID and password.  How do we do this?  I think it has to do with "passthrough authentication" or WindowsIdentity.  Been Googling for it, but if anyone has a quick answer, I'd sure appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'access a server'?  It doesn't sound like you're using NTLM in your working case but basic authentication.  NTLM is challenge / response over HTTP and works like this: http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html

Answer (score 1):

Can you use WinHTTP instead of WinInet? Take a look at this [library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/featured_win_HTTP_wrapper.aspx) which wraps WinHTTP. I think it uses WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser() to get this info for you. I made requests through a Microsoft ISA proxy configured to use NTLM without any issues, so I'd assume it would identify as you against another server with NTLM.